# How to generate a hex file in RISC-V

Tags: riscv

Now, I'm implemented an ASP (Application Specific Processor) and I want to develop it with an RISC-type architecture. Reading a bit on the web, I concluded that the best option is to use RISC-V.

The idea is to develop a design in Verilog so that it can run the RISC-V ISA. And the software application that the processor should run is very simple, only a few arithmetic operations. For this reason as it is only one application it is not necessary that the processor supports an operating system.

I'm thinking of generating a hex file from my C application and loading the file into a ROM memory. But I could not find how I can generate the hex file from my code in C?

I built correctly my program with **riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc**

### $ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o hello hello.c

But I don't know how to generate a hex file.

Could someone tell me how can I create this file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the program `elf2hex`, which is installed when building the RISC-V toolchain. You can see an example of generating hex files in the riscv-tests/benchmark repository's Makefile (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/blob/master/benchmarks/Makefile):

```
%.hex: %
    elf2hex 16 32768 $< > $@
```

And the usage:

```
elf2hex <width> <depth> <elf_file>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I saw the example of riscv-tests/benchmark. I ran $make and it generated files as for example mm.riscv.dump, mm.riscv, mm.o and mm.riscv.hex, it for each benchmark. However, I don't know because  for each hex file of the benchmarks, the hex file in all positions has only zeros.       00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Even, I ran my own program and the result was the same, the hex file are only zeros in all positions. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: The riscv-tests/benchmarks hex files are definitely not all zeros. The "depth" parameter, 32kB used for the riscv-tests, is overkill for the tiny benchmarks, so naturally most of the hex file will be zero, but not all.

Comment: Ooh, You have reason, I just did a little visual inspection and I mistakenly thought that all values were zero.                                                                                          
Thank you very much for the help.