# How can I generate a hexfile from C code for testing a 32-bit RISC-V hardware design?

Tags: hardware, riscv

I have a hardware design in Verilog developed on the basis of Berkeley's Vscale processor. For testing the design I want to compile some C programs and generate hexfiles. I eventually want to generate ROMs from hexfiles and perform Verilog simulations. Which compiler best serves the purpose, riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc or riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc? The architecture of Vscale processor is RV32IM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a hex file in RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321469/how-to-generate-a-hex-file-in-risc-v)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use elf2hex command in order to create a .hex file from the elf file (created using gcc -o),
 i.e: `elf2hex 16 4096 my_elf_file > output.hex`
If you are going to use a 32-bits architecture, I would compile using riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc.

Comment: Can I directly run the code generated by riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc on my processor? I think, riscv-tests repo generates code that can be directly run on my processor but those are assembly programs. How can I generate such code from C programs?

Comment: Using elf2hex as recommended above. You can also look at Makefiles of riscv_tests to understand how they are generated.

Comment: Yes you can. As mention above, take a look at the Makefile, in this case inside benchmarks folder at test repo. It creates an executable and a .hex from a C file. Then you can use spike, load it in a fpga, etc.
ie `riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -o myexecutable.riscv mycode.c` and run it using `spike (-d option if you want to debug) pk myexecutable.riscv`

Answer (score 3):

I currently use objcopy for testing of my core design. The current version of gcc contains a [patch](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-04/msg00321.html) which enables objcopy to output verilog memory files.

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy -O verilog input.elf output.vh
```

I can load these files easily into my simulation in modelsim.

But to answer your question, this would generate hex files in the intel format.

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy -O ihex input.elf output.hex
```

Objcopy also supports specifying which code sections to export and at which memory locations.